# Access Denied when trying to automate the MakeMy trip website using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the MakeMy trip website using Selenium Webdriver in Java with Google Chrome. My script is failing once I click on the Search button. Error message:

```
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.makemytrip.com/flight/search?" on this server.
Reference #18.4d5ddb17.1557671136.2b95fb
```

I have tried running it manually on Chrome and found it to be running fine. However, through my Java code it's failing due to the above permissions issue. Any leads?

```java
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.qa.uiMap.AgentDetails;
import com.qa.uiMap.Flights;
import com.qa.uiMap.HomePage;
import com.qa.uiMap.PropertyDetails;
import com.qa.uiMap.PropertyListing;

import ExcelReader.ExcelReader;

public class SearchFlightResultsTest2 {

    WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        baseUrl = "https://www.makemytrip.com/";
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        ExcelReader.testDataExcelFileName = "TestExcel.xlsx";
        ExcelReader.setExcelFileSheet("PropertySearchTest");
    }

    //  @BeforeMethod
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void closePromoImages() throws NoSuchFrameException {

        try {
            driver.switchTo().frame("webklipper-publisher-widget-container-notification-frame");
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(HomePage.imgPromotionClose(driver)));
            if (HomePage.imgPromotionClose(driver).isDisplayed()) {
                HomePage.imgPromotionClose(driver).click();
            }
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
            // Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void selectTripOption() throws InterruptedException {

        //      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        //      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(HomePage.icnSelectOption(driver, "Flights")));

        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(100))
                .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(600))
                .ignoring(WebDriverException.class);

        WebElement we = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                WebElement optionFlights = HomePage.icnSelectOption(driver, "Flights");
                if (optionFlights.isDisplayed()) {
                    optionFlights.click();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Missing Flight Option");
                } 
                return optionFlights;
            }
        });

        //      we.click();
        Assert.assertEquals(HomePage.icnSelectOption(driver, "Flights").isDisplayed(), true,
                "Flight option is selectd sucessfully.");
    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void selectTripType() throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(Flights.rdbSelectTripOption(driver, "Round Trip")));
        if (Flights.rdbSelectTripOption(driver, "Round Trip").isDisplayed()) {
            Flights.rdbSelectTripOption(driver, "Round Trip").click();
            Assert.assertEquals(Flights.rdbSelectTripOption(driver, "Round Trip").isDisplayed(), true,
                    "Round Type flight option is selected sucessfully.");
        } else {
            // System.out.println("Round Type flight option is not Available :: fail");
            Assert.assertEquals(Flights.rdbSelectTripOption(driver, "Round Trip").isDisplayed(), false,
                    "Round Type flight option is missing.");
        }

    }

    @Test(priority = 4)
    public void selectFromCity() throws InterruptedException {

        if (Flights.txtFromCity(driver).isDisplayed()) {
            Flights.txtFromCity(driver).sendKeys("Delhi");
            Flights.txtFromCity(driver).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("From City Delhi Selected");
        } else {
            // System.out.println("Round Type flight option is not Available :: fail");
            //          Assert.assertEquals(Flights.rdbSelectTripOption(driver, "Round Trip").isDisplayed(), false,
            //                  "Round Type flight option is missing.");
        }

    }

    @Test(priority = 5)
    public void selectToCity() throws InterruptedException {

        if (Flights.txtToCity(driver).isDisplayed()) {
            Flights.txtToCity(driver).sendKeys("Banglore");
            Flights.txtToCity(driver).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("To City Banglore Selected");
        } else {
        }

    }

    @Test(priority = 6)
    public void selectDepartureDate() throws InterruptedException {

        if (Flights.txtDepartureDate(driver).isDisplayed()) {
            Flights.txtDepartureDate(driver).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Departure Date is Clicked");

            System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Month']/div/div[contains(text(),'May')]")).getText());

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Jun')]/../../div/div/div[@aria-disabled='false']/div/p[1][contains(text(),'16')]")).click();            
        } else {
        }
    }
    @Test(priority = 6)
    public void selectReturnDate() throws InterruptedException {

        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(100))
                .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(600))
                .ignoring(WebDriverException.class);

        WebElement we = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                WebElement returnDate = Flights.txtReturnDate(driver);
                if (returnDate.isDisplayed()) {
//                  returnDate.click();
                    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Month']/div/div[contains(text(),'May')]")).getText());              
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Jun')]/../../div/div/div[@aria-disabled='false']/div/p[1][contains(text(),'26')]")).click();

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Return Dates are not selected");
                } 
                return returnDate;
            }
        });
    }

    @Test(priority = 7)
    public void clickSearch() throws InterruptedException {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(100))
                .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(600))
                .ignoring(WebDriverException.class);

        WebElement we = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                WebElement btnSearch = Flights.btnSearch(driver, "Search");
                if (btnSearch.isDisplayed()) {
                    btnSearch.click();

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Missing Search Button ");
                } 
                return btnSearch;
            }
        });

    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue while automate the makemytrip website. Adding `WebDriver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();` solved the issue.
Above is done in C#

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I had the same problem but now it's working since adding WebDriver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();

Answer (score 0):

In the error message you have -> "http://www.makemytrip.com/**flight**/search"
 This link does not look like valid. (flights instead of flight worked for me)
Can you try the url -> "https://www.makemytrip.com/**flights**/search"

Comment: I have been using https://www.makemytrip.com/flights/ => URL on Page 1. When I select City dates and click on Search Button URL comes out to be https://www.makemytrip.com/flight/search?itinerary=DEL-BLR-16/05/2019_BLR-DEL-25/05/2019&tripType=R&paxType=A-1_C-0_I-0&intl=false&=&cabinClass=E.  This is where my Chrome Browser is giving an error below                                                  Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.makemytrip.com/flight/search?" on this server.
Reference #18.4d5ddb17.1557671136.2b95fb

Comment: @Bharat, I think its some restriction from the site. 
One workaround would be-> Use the search url which appears after you click on search. This worked for me. : Eg:
````
driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/flight/search?itinerary=DEL-BOM-15/05/2019&tripType=O&paxType=A-1_C-0_I-0&intl=false&=&cabinClass=E");
````

Comment: It worked for me finally.. It's happening due to missing -   driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
After adding this post launching driver it started working for me.

Comment: Wow, that option helped me with tatacliq too.